# Отладить методы в PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, функции

Всем привет помогите правильно отладить методы в классах и где про это почитать?

Есть родительский класс Objects/product.php и в нём метод читать все записи из таблицы!

```
class product{
    public $conn;
    public $table_name = "dvd";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $scu;
    public $img;
    public $name;
    public $price;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    //query to read all notes from `dvd` table
    public  function readAll(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table_name . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Дочерний класс Objects/dvd.php перенимает этот метод

```
require_once 'product.php';
class dvd extends product {

    // database connection and table name
    // object properties
    public $capacity;
    public function readAll(){
       dvd::readAll();;
    }
```

И должно этот метод вывести в данные на страницу dvd.php

```
include_once 'Objects/dvd.php';
include_once 'DB/database.php';
// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$dvd = new dvd($db);
$dvd->readAll();
echo "<div data-price='{$dvd->price}' class='item'>";
echo "<a href='dvd_id.php?id={$dvd->id}'><img class='product' src='UI/images/{$dvd->img}'></a> ";
echo "<div class='info'>";
echo "<h6 align='center'> <a href='dvd_id.php?id={$dvd->id}'></a>{$dvd->name}</h6> ";
echo "<p class='descroption'>ID number: {$dvd->id} </p>";
echo "<p class='descroption'>SKU number: {$dvd->scu} </p>";
echo "<p class='descroption'>Price: {$dvd->price} <i class='glyphicon-euro'></i></p>";
echo "<p class='descroption'>Capacity: {$dvd->capacity}  MB</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Как правильно это отладить, и где почитать про это, буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: А что именно не работает? Какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: Изменил дочерний класс поменял:
`parent::readAll();` на 
`dvd::readAll()`

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TreeList/ProductList/Objects/dvd.php on line 15

Comment: Из вашего дочернего класса можно удалить все, кроме `public $capacity;`, так как все остальные методы и свойства и так наследуются

Comment: А зачем вы это сделали? Смысл какой? Не говоря уж о том, что `dvd::readAll()` - это синтаксис доступа к статическому методу, а он у вас совсем не такой

Comment: вернул обратно 
`public function readAll() { parent::readAll(); }` ошибок нет но и данных из базы тоже

Comment: Проверьте, что запрос отрабатывает верно. После `$stmt->execute();` поставьте `var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());` (если у вас PDO. Если нет, то посмотрите в документации соответствующие функции) и посмотрите, что ответит. Если ошибок нет, то выведите через `var_dump` результирующий набор. Если он пуст - запустите свой запрос прямо на БД

Comment: А вообще, у вас ничего не выводит потому, что для начала надо бы извлечь результат из `$stmt`, а потом в цикле по нему пройтись

Comment: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }` вот что написал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно прочитать и вывести все записи из определенной таблицы. Если так, то ваш код совсем не про то.

Давайте распишем задачу по шагам:

1) Читаем набор строк из таблицы `dvd`

2) Для каждой строки из набора создаем объект класса `Dvd`

3) Выводим все эти объекты в виде таблицы

По факту вы не решили ни одной из этих задач.

Логика проектирования должна быть примерно такая:

Класс `Product`. Он должен быть а) абстрактным б) содержать поля и методы общие для всех его потомков в) всяко не должен содержать логики чтения всех записей из БД (он вообще не должен знать про БД)

```
abstract class Product
{
    public $id;
    public $scu;
    public $img;
    public $name;
    public $price;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        // $data - это строка извлеченная из БД. 
        // Соответственно индексы - это имена полей в таблице
        $this->id    = $data['id'];
        $this->img   = $data['img'];
        $this->scu   = $data['scu'];
        $this->name  = $data['name'];
        $this->price = $data['price'];
    }
}
```

Его потомок, класс `Dvd`добавляет одно поле

```
class Dvd extends Product
{
    public $capacity;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->capacity = $data['capacity'];
    }

}
```

Извлекаем данные из БД и создаем массив нужных продуктов

```
$dvdList = [];
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM dvd ORDER BY id DESC');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $dvdList[$row['id']] = new Dvd($row);
}
```

Выводим их на экран

```
foreach ($dvdList as $dvd) {
    echo "
        <div data-price='{$dvd->price}' class='item'>
            <a href='dvd_id.php?id={$dvd->id}'><img class='product' src='UI/images/{$dvd->img}'></a> 
            <div class='info'>
                <h6 align='center'> <a href='dvd_id.php?id={$dvd->id}'></a>{$dvd->name}</h6> 
                <p class='descroption'>ID number: {$dvd->id} </p>
                <p class='descroption'>SKU number: {$dvd->scu} </p>
                <p class='descroption'>Price: {$dvd->price} <i class='glyphicon-euro'></i></p>
                <p class='descroption'>Capacity: {$dvd->capacity}  MB</p>
            </div>
        </div>";
}
```